# Compute the maximum value by group and by a time "window"

Tags: r, max

For the following Panel data (Tracking the Value for unit "ID" over "Time" :

```
ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
Time=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
Value=c(1,9,4,8,5,2,5,9,7,6)
```

I would like to create a vector which is a maximum value for each "ID" over the *last two days* (assuming that the unit of Time is a day)

Output vector "Max_Value" would be as follows:

```
Max_Value=c(1,9,9,8,8,2,5,9,9,7)
```

To clarify, here's how Max_Value is computed for ID "1".

For ID "1", the maximum value by the "Time=1" is 1, which is a maximum of {1}.

Similarly, for ID "1", the maximum value at the "Time 2" is 9, which is a maximum of {1,9}.

Again, for ID "1", the maximum value at the "Time 3" is 9, which is a maximum of {9,4}.

For ID "1", the maximum value at the "Time 4" is 8, which is a maximum of {4,8}.

For ID "1", the maximum value at the "Time 5" is 8, which is a maximum of {8,5}.

Comment: have you tried with ```tidyquant``` package?

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado Not yet. Could you refer the function?

Comment: The function is ```tq_transmute```. The vignette is this: https://cran.csiro.au/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ02-quant-integrations-in-tidyquant.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just have vectors and `Time` is complete and sorted, `slide` + `ave` could work well for you:

```
ave(Value, ID, FUN = function(x) slider::slide_dbl(x, max, .before=1))
#> [1] 1 9 9 8 8 2 5 9 9 7
```

Or even a full Base R solution:

```
Value[ave(Value, ID, FUN = function(x) c(0, -(diff(x)<0))) + seq_along(Value)]
#> [1] 1 9 9 8 8 2 5 9 9 7
```

---

Otherwise you can solve it with `dplyr` + `slider`:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(ID, Time, Value) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(Max_Value = slider::slide_index_dbl(Value, Time, max, .before=1)) %>% 
 ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       ID  Time Value Max_Value
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     1         1
#>  2     1     2     9         9
#>  3     1     3     4         9
#>  4     1     4     8         8
#>  5     1     5     5         8
#>  6     2     1     2         2
#>  7     2     2     5         5
#>  8     2     3     9         9
#>  9     2     4     7         9
#> 10     2     5     6         7
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 Time=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                 Value=c(1,9,4,8,5,2,5,9,7,6))

max_v <- function(x) max(dt[ID==x$ID & Time <= x$Time & Time > (x$Time-2) ,Value])

sapply(split(dt,1:nrow(dt)),max_v)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a `rollapply()` style function from `zoo` setting a width of 2:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
#Data
df <- data.frame(ID,Time,Value)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Max=rollapply(Value,width=2,FUN=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                       by=1, by.column=TRUE,partial=TRUE,fill=NA, align="right"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID  Time Value   Max
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1
 2     1     2     9     9
 3     1     3     4     9
 4     1     4     8     8
 5     1     5     5     8
 6     2     1     2     2
 7     2     2     5     5
 8     2     3     9     9
 9     2     4     7     9
10     2     5     6     7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Instead of "over the last two days" how can I set the length of window as "over the last 30 days" ? Would it be enough to replace "width=2" with "width=30"?

Comment: @SSP Yes, you are right, set window width to 30, as you mentioned. That is pretty correct :) Let me know if that was clear enough!

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` you also can try `frollapply` (fast rolling function). Note that `fill` is set to `first(Value)` in initial row of `ID` group where there is only one element available instead of two.

```
dt <- data.frame(ID,Time,Value)

setDT(dt)

dt[, ValueMax := frollapply(x = Value, 
                            n = 2, 
                            max, 
                            fill = first(Value), 
                            align = "right", 
                            na.rm = TRUE), 
   by = ID]
```

**Output**

```
    ID Time Value ValueMax
 1:  1    1     1        1
 2:  1    2     9        9
 3:  1    3     4        9
 4:  1    4     8        8
 5:  1    5     5        8
 6:  2    1     2        2
 7:  2    2     5        5
 8:  2    3     9        9
 9:  2    4     7        9
10:  2    5     6        7
```